# how can i parse xml to csv and save it in R?

Tags: r, xml, dataframe

How can I parse my xml data and save it as csv in R? Please see the input and output below

Input =

```
<patient id="559" weight="99" insulin_type="Novalog">
<glu_level>
<event ts="18-01-2022 00:01:00" value="179"/>
<event ts="18-01-2022 00:06:00" value="183"/>
<event ts="18-01-2022 00:11:00" value="187"/>
</glu_level>
<finger_stick>
<event ts="07-12-2021 01:03:20" value="107"/>
<event ts="07-12-2021 01:08:04" value="107"/>
<event ts="07-12-2021 05:08:14" value="191"/>
<event ts="07-12-2021 11:21:49" value="586"/>
</finger_stick>
</patient>
```

Output1 =

| time | glu_level |
| --- | --- |
| 18-01-2022 00:01:00 | 179 |
| 18-01-2022 00:06:00 | 183 |
| 18-01-2022 00:11:00 | 187 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may read the file `read_xml`, extract the attributes after  filtering for the 'glu_level'

```
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)
dat <- read_xml("input.xml")
glu <- dat %>% 
          xml_find_all("//glu_level/event") 
out <- tibble(time = glu %>% 
                xml_attr('ts'), glu_level = glu %>% 
                                          xml_attr('value'))
```

-output

```
> out
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  time                glu_level
  <chr>               <chr>    
1 18-01-2022 00:01:00 179      
2 18-01-2022 00:06:00 183      
3 18-01-2022 00:11:00 187
```

Comment: I did it,  many thanks for your help.